# What is the recommended pipeline or chain for text_general?

Tags: solr

I currently working on a project where I have to index and then search short paragraphs stored in a DB. The paragraphs are in more than one language (English, French, ...). A search can be for any word or any combination of words and should return all paragraphs where the word or words occur. A search should also return paragraphs where words that closely match the search word occur.
The difficulty I am facing is the get the right index and query pipeline, specially for names.

The Solr version I am using is 8.1.1. The DB is PostgreSQL.
The fieldtype I am using is text_general for the field in question.
The pipeline I am currently using is given below.

```
  <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true" positionIncrementGap="100" enableGraphQueries="true" multiValued="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal = "1"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.HyphenatedWordsFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>

    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" preserveOriginal = "1"/>
      <filter class="solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.ICUFoldingFilterFactory"/>
preserveOriginal="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Comment: To be able to say anything useful it'd be necessary to know what your current problem is and how you're having issues with names. Indexing each paragraph as a document would also be a requirement if the languages a intermingled in a single document, otherwise you can select a field depending on the language used (i.e. create a text_general_fr and text_general_en with appropriate processing).

Comment: I managed to get it work. Actually, there was a bug in another part of my code causing the pipeline not to work correctly. Thanks @MatsLindh for taking time to respond to my query.